# how to run blackberry emulator on mac

Tags: macos, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

How to run blackberry application on mac in eclipse? I have downloaded the eclipse with blackberry plugin installed in it... But i am facing problem when i am running new Hello Project in eclipse... I can't find blackberry simulator to run my project in run configuration... Please help me with some solution...

Answer (score 6):

Bit late but for anyone else looking the emulator doesn't work on a Mac, you need to test on a physical device:
http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/macosx.jsp
"Testing and Debugging

To test your application on a Mac environment, you’ll need to use a **physical BlackBerry smartphone** tethered to your computer and debug files that match the BlackBerry smartphone OS. Download debug files for Mac-based development tools."

You could install Windows on VirtualBox or some other virtualization tool and setup eclipse and the plugin there.

Answer (score 0):

If it's something you will be doing often, sign up for a testing site like [crossbrowsertesting.com](http://crossbrowsertesting.com), they have a decent emulator for Blackberry amongst all other commmon devices and your standard QA testing environments for desktop websites.

The blackberry emulator is a tad buggy though but its enough to get you going.

Comment: OP is asking to run the entire emulator, not just the BB browser.

Comment: well its an emulator like i said in my post. just because the site is called crossbrowsertesting, doesn't mean you cant simply press the close button on the device and have access to the rest of the emulator... Really the only issue I see is testing local environments, but if you have a staging server you can test other emulators locally and push changes to the staging server to test on the BB